# Steam shutdowns after logging into my account, Installed from Ubuntu 16.04.5 repository

Tags: 16.04, steam

My computer is based on AMD Athlon 64 and NVidea Geforce 7900 GS.

I had a fresh installation of Ubuntu 16.04.5. System offered to update some packages (as usual). After that I launched the command in terminal:

```
sudo apt install steam
```

It was installed without any error or warning. I launched Steam:

```
steam
```

During this command was running, I chose agreement with its policy, I logged into my account. The frame of steam window appeared and closed after a second. And no more.

Below is the listing from terminal during steam update.

```
ILocalize::AddFile() failed to load file "public/steambootstrapper_english.txt".
[2018-08-10 21:01:23] Startup - updater built Jun 16 2014 11:16:02
[2018-08-10 21:01:23] Verifying installation...
[2018-08-10 21:01:23] Unable to read and verify install manifest /home/ilsu87/.steam/package/steam_client_ubuntu12.installed
[2018-08-10 21:01:23] Verification complete
[2018-08-10 21:01:23] Downloading Update...
[2018-08-10 21:01:23] Checking for available update...
[2018-08-10 21:01:24] Package file tenfoot_misc_all.zip.1ca83d76835b4613170f5cead778b176b11f2b0c missing or incorrect size
[2018-08-10 21:01:24] Package file tenfoot_dicts_all.zip.33245b7d523f68418283e93b0572508fa127ee8f missing or incorrect size
[2018-08-10 21:01:24] Package file tenfoot_fonts_all.zip.vz.7673e4cd32b6752bc621d8bc1a7118a9af19b64a_12077027 missing or incorrect size
[2018-08-10 21:01:24] Package file tenfoot_ambientsounds_all.zip.89b80bcfdd11b2b99257ddbbdc374e2df54e2738 missing or incorrect size
[2018-08-10 21:01:24] Package file tenfoot_sounds_all.zip.vz.ffef2b2fc386819a842ea79484b966a937c2ca7e_1209792 missing or incorrect size
[2018-08-10 21:01:24] Package file tenfoot_images_all.zip.vz.8ab2c10a202a129283ce713602e1025367c7875e_31197583 missing or incorrect size
[2018-08-10 21:01:24] Package file tenfoot_all.zip.vz.63146b5c835d5922b35ce8acaf1223b854f63710_2549683 missing or incorrect size
[2018-08-10 21:01:24] Package file friendsui_all.zip.vz.c05309798f38320b90f9c7e2fccd88f5699b634a_2336906 missing or incorrect size
[2018-08-10 21:01:24] Package file resources_misc_all.zip.vz.4a1fa88d21b005b67a41a9a0fc6044ae1fa46791_2225211 missing or incorrect size
[2018-08-10 21:01:24] Package file resources_music_all.zip.vz.7a62e15083d4a65668f0d1fa58ad8c1b99fb5ace_3708050 missing or incorrect size
[2018-08-10 21:01:24] Package file resources_hidpi_all.zip.vz.9771a83bbf89f9dac69342dda233a169945343a0_47673 missing or incorrect size
[2018-08-10 21:01:24] Package file resources_all.zip.vz.3be5627f991177657caaba8e22d21ae0ab142fbd_1244133 missing or incorrect size
[2018-08-10 21:01:24] Package file strings_en_all.zip.vz.52018013d5d162b017869e2fff5ba2420b91e38e_88307 missing or incorrect size
[2018-08-10 21:01:24] Package file strings_all.zip.vz.4f5b8638ac82410b08b560caab72e2ae02e993a9_2256835 missing or incorrect size
[2018-08-10 21:01:24] Package file public_all.zip.vz.f129a70b2c5ea343234731d072e6e54cdd52c91a_792213 missing or incorrect size
[2018-08-10 21:01:24] Package file bins_ubuntu12.zip.vz.a92521196485f369bc646aacc4b3c73dc317a2ec_17610594 missing or incorrect size
[2018-08-10 21:01:24] Package file bins_pub_ubuntu12.zip.vz.ce5379d09553179798ec56b6198deb769626bbc3_9057612 missing or incorrect size
[2018-08-10 21:01:24] Package file bins_sdk_ubuntu12.zip.vz.feb18730fee7b172a7dbc74f434ca28c741bc5da_11771891 missing or incorrect size
[2018-08-10 21:01:24] Package file bins_codecs_ubuntu12.zip.vz.228ce3d6bd2f702a390c63cef6158d21ba57c9e5_2373711 missing or incorrect size
[2018-08-10 21:01:24] Package file bins_misc_ubuntu12.zip.vz.4e6b30bf5d7e44b35ff9c14ec30529fbe722f4ba_1553789 missing or incorrect size
[2018-08-10 21:01:24] Package file webkit_ubuntu12.zip.vz.c491ba9e081007ec471ef92509b015bae51f3756_46838449 missing or incorrect size
[2018-08-10 21:01:24] Package file miles_ubuntu12.zip.vz.4fd048667c97ef6eb976f4c42ce5c18f8695ac9e_295483 missing or incorrect size
[2018-08-10 21:01:24] Package file sdl2_ubuntu12.zip.vz.55db1c88c0f8bb1c1847aa08cbfb366e160bbf69_644936 missing or incorrect size
[2018-08-10 21:01:24] Package file steam_ubuntu12.zip.vz.8c6fa69c931c0af758a021607e8a94ecd0e8d230_1501602 missing or incorrect size
[2018-08-10 21:01:24] Package file runtime_part0_ubuntu12.zip.8cce4571d13c0cea4890ffd2155fc09c590f7138 missing or incorrect size
[2018-08-10 21:01:24] Package file runtime_part1_ubuntu12.zip.f1d635f3a30a64e3a30ae13f222ecb89f9699ebe missing or incorrect size
[2018-08-10 21:01:24] Downloading update (0 of 280 140 KB)...
[2018-08-10 21:01:24] Downloading update (194 of 280 140 KB)...
[2018-08-10 21:01:24] Downloading update (288 of 280 140 KB)...
[2018-08-10 21:01:25] Downloading update (876 of 280 140 KB)...
/// cutted some lines
[2018-08-10 21:04:12] Downloading update (279 086 of 280 140 KB)...
[2018-08-10 21:04:13] Downloading update (279 506 of 280 140 KB)...
[2018-08-10 21:04:13] Downloading update (279 927 of 280 140 KB)...
[2018-08-10 21:04:13] Downloading update (280 140 of 280 140 KB)...
[2018-08-10 21:04:14] Download Complete.
[2018-08-10 21:04:14] uninstalled manifest found in /home/ilsu87/.steam/package/steam_client_ubuntu12 (1).
[2018-08-10 21:04:14] Extracting package...
[2018-08-10 21:04:48] Installing update...
[2018-08-10 21:04:50] Cleaning up...
[2018-08-10 21:04:50] Update complete, launching...
[2018-08-10 21:04:50] Shutdown
Running Steam on ubuntu 16.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Found newer runtime version for 64-bit libpangox-1.0.so.0. Host: 0.0.0 Runtime: 0.3000.0
Found newer runtime version for 64-bit libGLU.so.1. Host: 1.3.1 Runtime: 1.3.8004
Found newer runtime version for 64-bit libdbusmenu-glib.so.4. Host: 4.0.12 Runtime: 4.0.13
Found newer runtime version for 64-bit libdbusmenu-gtk.so.4. Host: 4.0.12 Runtime: 4.0.13
[2018-08-10 21:05:37] Startup - updater built Aug  8 2018 21:32:23
[2018-08-10 21:05:37] Verifying installation...
[2018-08-10 21:05:37] Unable to read and verify install manifest /home/ilsu87/.steam/package/steam_client_ubuntu12.installed
[2018-08-10 21:05:37] Verification complete
[2018-08-10 21:05:37] Downloading update...
[2018-08-10 21:05:37] Checking for available updates...
[2018-08-10 21:05:38] Download complete.
[2018-08-10 21:05:38] uninstalled manifest found in /home/ilsu87/.steam/package/steam_client_ubuntu12 (1).
[2018-08-10 21:05:38] Extracting package...
[2018-08-10 21:06:13] Installing update...
[2018-08-10 21:06:22] Cleaning up...
[2018-08-10 21:06:22] Update complete, launching Steam...
[2018-08-10 21:06:22] Shutdown
Restarting Steam by request...
Running Steam on ubuntu 16.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME has been set by the user to: /home/ilsu87/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime
Pins up-to-date!
[2018-08-10 21:06:25] Startup - updater built Aug  8 2018 21:32:23
[2018-08-10 21:06:25] Verifying installation...
[2018-08-10 21:06:25] Verification complete
Forced create but already created for SharedObjectEvent
Forced create but already created for SharedObjectEvent
Forced create but already created for SharedObjectEvent
Forced create but already created for SharedObjectEvent
Forced create but already created for SharedObjectEvent
Forced create but already created for SharedObjectEvent
Forced create but already created for SharedObjectEvent
Forced create but already created for SharedObjectEvent
Forced create but already created for SharedObjectEvent
Forced create but already created for SharedObjectEvent
Forced create but already created for SharedObjectEvent
Forced create but already created for SharedObjectEvent
Forced create but already created for SharedObjectEvent
Forced create but already created for SharedObjectEvent
Forced create but already created for SharedObjectEvent
Forced create but already created for SharedObjectEvent
Forced create but already created for SharedObjectEvent
Forced create but already created for SharedObjectEvent
Forced create but already created for SharedObjectEvent
```

Comment: After changing video driver to recommended proprietary nvidia-304, I was unable to log into Ubuntu due to error in system program. So I reinstalled Ubuntu 16.04.5.

Comment: Commands from [Steam installation guide](https://steamcommunity.com/app/221410/discussions/0/492378265880655938/) did nothing with the problem. `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa` and `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

Comment: Problem solved for Linux Mint 17.3 and 18.3, where installation nvidia-304 driver doesn't break the system. But there is another problem with Steam build-in browser not opening its sites.